# How do I use BIND DNS with multiple domain names?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-xp, bind, subdomain

I am trying to set up a simple local DNS server to use across multiple virtual machines in a dev/test environment (web servers). While I would just set up a Windows server with DNS, I have limited memory available so I would rather just run BIND on my host OS (Widows XP Pro).

I found [this great tutorial](http://alex.charrett.com/bind-on-windows-mainmenu-3) that got me up and running with BIND on a single domain. After the setup I was able to use my knowledge of DNS control panels that I am used to to set up a few records. Unfortunately, the assumption in the tutorial was that I would only want to manage DNS for one domain and I have two domains.

I have been through tons of documentation and I have tried duplicating the zone file and copying and pasting the "zone" section in named.conf, but that didn't work. I also tried putting the other domain's records right into my original zone file without success. Following the example, my zone file currently looks like this:

```
$TTL 6h
@   IN SOA  ns1.mydomain.com.   info.mydomain.com. (
            2011052302
            10800
            3600
            604800
            86400 )

@       NS  ns1.mydomain.com.

ns1 IN A    10.225.0.51

test    IN A    10.225.0.1

$ORIGIN test.mydomain.com.
www IN A    10.225.0.1
www2    IN A    10.226.0.66
```

This currently resolves for:

1. test.mydomain.com
2. www.test.mydomain.com
3. www2.test.mydomain.com

I need to also make the server resolve:

1. test.myotherdomain.com
2. www.test.myotherdomain.com
3. ftp.test.myotherdomain.com

I am not interested in how many ways it can be achieved or best practices (this is a test enovironment), I am just trying to find 1 way to get it to resolve records for both mydomain.com and myotherdomain.com. If it can be done in 1 zone file, that is fine. If it requires multiple zone files, please explain how to configure them (following the tutorial I linked to) so they will be read by BIND.

**Update**

Through more tinkering and help from you guys I discovered where I went horribly wrong - I was having conflicts with the public DNS because both mydomain.com and myotherdomain.com are online. I had the file structure and named.conf set up correctly before. However, I had to set up my local DNS to be authoritive for test.mydomain.com and test.myotherdomain.com (vs mydomain.com and myotherdomain.com) and then put in the A records only for the "test" subdomain.

```
$TTL 6h

@   IN SOA  ns1.test.mydomain.com.  info.mydomain.com. (
            2011052304
            10800
            3600
            604800
            86400 )

@       NS  ns1.test.mydomain.com.

ns1 IN A    10.225.0.51
www IN A    10.225.0.171
db  IN A    10.225.0.171
ftp IN A    10.225.0.171
```

Comment: If ever a question screamed out for an RTFM answer this is it! If you've "been through tons of documentation" I can only suggest doing it again and this time reading it properly.

Comment: He's stuck using bind -if there is a manual page that explains this why not post the link.  it's not his fault he thinks windows will use more ram - he's a developer.

Comment: Actually, it is the fact that I need to run multiple virtual machines that eats up the RAM, not because I am running BIND. I am using bind because Windows XP Pro doesn't include DNS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add another zone entry, similar to the existing one in the named.conf file, with the DNS name and file name of your second domain.

Answer (score 2):

When you create another zone in Bind, you add another section to named.conf and point it to another data file (db.test.myotherdomain.com).

Comment: And since SF is for professional admins, your question is likely to be closed as off topic.

Comment: Why would you automatically assume I am not being paid for this (I am) just because I know nothing about setting up BIND? It just so happens I am a developer full-time and an admin part-time.